# VSCode PHP Intelephense show error when using Memcached

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm using Memcached in code, it shows this:

> error: "Undefined type 'Memcached'."

How to disable this error?
Version using:
VScode 1.41
PHP Intelephense 1.3.5

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just be mindful that there is [`memcached`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) and [`memcache`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) (without `d`)

Comment: The question should not contain links to images of code and errors, they belong in the question as text. What you have now, won't potentially help someone else in a Google/Stack Overflow search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `Memcached` to `intelephense.stubs` setting.

Reference: [Undefined type Memcached](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1291)

VS Code: 1.52.1

PHP Intelephense: 1.5.4

Answer (score 20):

You can disable the undefined type in intelephense vscode setting. To open the setting you can type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

[image]

Comment: When you do that, you no longer have the ability to get hints on that type. However, I noticed that if I have the corresponding file open on another tab, the error dissapears and I can peek on the type. How do I set it up so PHP intelephense knows where the class file lives?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working, simply try and restart your ide, it should work. seems to be a bug , especially caused if you move files around directly in the file system.
Otherwise correct your code then.

NB: The other solutions above may work but are hacks. They may be temporal fixes and lead to unwanted effects. Don't alter any IDE settings you do not understand or remember to reconfigure later, it can be such a pain to maintain your environment.

Comment: Reopen VSC worked for me.

Comment: glad it was helpful. I understand the tool could be buggy, but don't know why first instincts one would have is disabling the feature